# Simple server redirect to another domain doesnt work with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Android|iPhone|iPod|Blackberry) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.reports.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.reports.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

That wont redirect to my new domain.. why?!!?

Comment: is mod_rewrite working ?? have you tried simple redirect without any condition? Please check for AllowOverride All

Comment: In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf  change AllowOverride None to
AllowOverride All. Also look here http://ndesign-studio.com/blog/301-htaccess-redirect .Only for testing your mod_rewrite look at section "To Redirect Entire Site"

Comment: Dmitry, this will only redirect if (i) rewriting is enabled as per above comments and (ii) the user agent includes one of the words Android, iPhone, iPod or Blackberry.  Have you checked your access and error logs to see what is going on?  Can you or are you running on a shared service?  Have you checked that _any_ rewrite works?

Comment: I made a simple rule.. to redirect any url to google.. it didnt work. I dont know if the server can give me an access to the logs , I will check!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.reports.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You are missing the `http://`.